# ¿Como hacer para que una segunda imagen pueda darle click y me envíe a otra pagina?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Hola mi problema es que tengo 2 iconos de diferente color el primero está normal y cuando se pone el mouse encima aparece el segundo icono. Estoy trabajando en Wordpress pero le metí código Javascript y HTML pero ahora no se donde poner la referencia en la segunda imagen ya lo intente en ambos lados con a href, a href target y nada.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar8, false);

function iniciar8() {   
  var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen8'), original = imagen.src;
  
  imagen.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
      this.src = "http://34.217.38.217/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/img1-e1590772054999.png"
   
    
  }, false);
  imagen.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
      this.src = original;
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<img id="imagen8" class="aligncenter" src="http://34.217.38.217/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/img2_over.png" width="51" height="50" />
```

Comment: java y javascript son lenguajes totalmente distintos y el uno no tiene nada que ver con el otro... en una pagina web normal no puedes correr Java directamente, lo que corres es JavaScript, en aquello que haz puesto no hay nada de codigo de Java.

Answer (score 1):

No creo que sea necesario usar JavaScript para crear el enlace, es suficiente con que envuelvas el elemento de la imagen con un elemento de enlace para que cuando se haga click te envíe a la ruta que la otra imagen:

```
<a href="http://34.217.38.217/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/img1-e1590772054999.png">
    <img class="aligncenter" src="http://34.217.38.217/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/img2_over.png" width="51" height="50" />
</a>
```